# How to trigger pipelines in GitLab CI

Tags: triggers, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have the problem, that I want to trigger another pipeline (B) in antoher project (B), only when the deploy job in pipeline (A) is finished. But my configuration starts the second pipeline as soon as the deploy job in pipeline (A) starts. How can I do it, that the second pipeline is triggered, only when the deploy job in pipeline (A) in projet (A) is finished?

Here is my gitlab-ci.yml

> 

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'

before_script:
  - gem install bundler
  - bundle install

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - bundle exec jekyll build -d public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  rules:
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'

staging:
  variables:
    ENVIRONMENT: staging
  stage: build
  trigger: example/example


test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - bundle exec jekyll build -d test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "master"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare [stages order](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages), so gitlab pipeline don't know what order are expected.

At the beginning of `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file add something like this (or whatever order you want):

```yaml
stages:
  - deploy
  - test
  - build

# rest of you file...
```

Alternatively you can use [`needs`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) to build jobs relation.